# Javascript infinite recursive function crashes Chromium 50 ARM64 lib on Android 10

Tags: crash, chromium, v8, android-10.0, javascript-debugger

My Android app use web view like control based on Chromium 50 (V8 JavaScript engine 5.0). Using system WebView or newer Chromium version is not an option because of various reasons.

I receive a lot of `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)` crashes on Android 10 and arm64 version of the binary only. The same binary with older Android versions as well as 32 bit version of the binary with Android 10 has no problem.

Here is an example code containing infinite recursive function which crashes:
`webView.evaluateJavascript("(function a(i) { a(i++); })()", null);`

Stack trace from Android studio debugger:

```
art_sigsegv_fault 0x000000753da02e9c
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x000000753da033a4
___lldb_unnamed_symbol24$$app_process64 0x0000005ca3207da8
<unknown> 0x00000075c3f888c0
<unknown> 0x00000074784191e8
<unknown> 0x00000074784191e8
<unknown> 0x00000074784191e8
<unknown> 0x00000074784191e8
<unknown> 0x00000074784191e8
............... the same line 15560 times
<unknown> 0x000000747830be94
<unknown> 0x000000747841937c
<unknown> 0x0000007478339a28
<unknown> 0x000000747831fe30
```

Any ideas how to avoid these crashes are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 developer here. The link you mentioned talks about *system* libraries. I don't know of any reason why V8 would try to read system libraries. Are you sure that's what's happening? Can you run a Debug build and get a stack trace? Without further data, I would suspect that there's something else that's going on and causing those crashes.

FWIW:

`--untrusted-code-mitigations` causes the (optimizing) compiler to emit code sequences that (partially) mitigate the recently discovered "spectre" CPU security bugs. That's totally unrelated to Android 10 compatibility.

`--jitless` turns off all just-in-time code generation in new enough versions of V8 (at a significant performance cost, of course). That, too, is unrelated to execute-only memory for Android system binaries.

**Update** after updated question, and discussion in comments:

Based on the stack trace, it seems that the process crashes when it runs out of stack space. V8 is supposed to detect that situation and throw a `RangeError` before that happens; the mechanism to accomplish that works by knowing an estimate of how much stack space will be available to a process. Apparently for (at least) the specific combination of your app running on Android 10, there is less remaining stack space than V8 v5.0 expects. A workaround is to run with the flag `--stack-size=800`, or alternatively, to edit the `V8_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE_KB` constant in `src/globals.h`.

A note to other readers: setting `--stack-size` to a huge value will not magically give you deeper recursion limits; instead it will let your process crash when the operating system defined stack limit is exceeded, rather than throwing a `RangeError`. Setting `--stack-size` too low will mean that JavaScript code won't be able to have many deep function calls (or, in the extreme, not run at all) before throwing a `RangeError`. It is generally recommended to leave this flag alone, unless you're running into a specific issue like here, where a small adjustment helps.

Comment: Hello jmrk! Thank you very much for your comment and for the information about the flags. 
I guessed that these crashes are caused by XOM because they appear only with Android 10 and arm64 version of the binary.
But it seems you're right that it's not related to XOM because here is an example code containing infinite recursive function which crashes:
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function a(i) { a(i++); })()", null);


The same binary with older Android versions as well as 32 bit version of the binary with Android 10 has no problem.

Comment: When infinite recursion leads to a crash, then that always smells of a stack overflow that wasn't caught correctly. It could well be that there's a bug in that old V8 version, or maybe simply an incompatibility with the newer Android; for example if the operating system gives less stack to user-space processes, then the V8-internal limit for how much stack to use for JS functions would need to be adapted. (This is just a wild guess; I still recommend running in a debugger and getting a backtrace to figure out what's going on.)

Comment: I made debug build of my webview library but the unstripped version of the lib is 3.2 GB. That's why I used stripped Debug build. To get a backtrace I got the tombstone file from my phone a symbolize it using the following command: third_party/android_platform/development/scripts/stack --arch=arm64 --output-directory out/Debug tombstone > tombstone.txt. You can find a link to it in my question. It seem it does not provide proper backtrace. I will try another methods.

Comment: I don't know why there are so many stack traces in that output, or how to identify which one is relevant. If it's the first, then it looks like a check failure somewhere in ART. The fault address 0x7495cdfff8 looks like something may have erroneously read the end of the preceding page of memory. Nowhere in the output is "v8" mentioned at all, so I see no evidence that V8 is involved in whatever is going wrong, and therefore I don't think I can help further here, sorry.

Comment: Stack traces are so many because they are for all threads. We are interested in the first one named Chrome_InProcRe but as you can see it has only one line stack trace. I'm trying to compile unstripped debug binary to get more informative stack trace but so far unsuccessful. I posted the stack trace from Android Studio debugger when the app crashes.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread the output. You can try lowering the limit where V8's internal stack check would trigger and cause a RangeError. Try `--stack-size=900` or even 800. If recompiling is easier than passing flags, you can edit V8_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE_KB in src/globals.h. Does that help?

Comment: Yes! --stack-size=800 does the trick. No more crashes on Android 10! Please copy this to your answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much for your professional help! Is it safe to keep this option for x86 and 32 bit binaries?

Comment: Thanks for reporting back; I've added `--stack-size` to my answer. Yes, it should be safe to keep that option for other platforms. You'll lose a bit of maximum recursion depth, that's all.