# Constant stack size in Chrome Web Worker despite varying --js-flags stack size arguments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

I am using the following code to estimate the size of the stack inside a Web Worker in Google Chrome running on Linux (x86_64):

```js
var i = 0;
function recurse () {
    i++;
    recurse();
}
try {
    recurse();
} catch (ex) {
    alert('maxStackSize = ' + i + '\nerror: ' + ex);
}
```

I am finding however that regardless of what I set the stack size argument to I always get the same value: 6969 with the devtools closed or 6968 with the devtools open. I always close all other instances of Chrome before beginning my test and I run Chrome from the terminal as follows:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --incognito
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --incognito --js-flags="--stack-size 2048"
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --incognito --js-flags="--stack-size 128"
```

Chrome seems to be accepting the arguments (checked via intentionally misspelling them/putting in invalid values), so I do think `--js-flags` is being parsed but it does not seem to have any effect on the depth of the stack. Why is this the case?

**Update**

Setting `--js-flags="--stack-size XYZ"` does effect the main thread. Workers on the other hand seem fixed to a stack size of around 495 kb.

Comment: [This question looks relevant.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505070/javascript-infinite-recursive-function-crashes-chromium-50-arm64-lib-on-android) My reading of the answer makes me think that your "--stack-size" is there to tell V8 how much stack to *expect*, and is not how the actual amount of stack is allocated by the platform.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, it seems though that changing this flag does effect the size of the stack in the main thread, just not in the workers.

Comment: Ah, interesting.

Comment: I believe this is [the flag](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/flags/flag-definitions.h#2105) that allows overriding the stack size. It defaults to `V8_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE_KB` which should be 800 kb+ depending on the platform, however, it seems then that the stack size for workers is unrelated to this constant/flag...